# Displaying Custom Posts on a Page

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I have created a page template and custom post type 'pa' that I want to display on the page template. I have the template created, also made `archive-pa.php`, `single-pa.php`
My template: `page-pa.php` contains this:

```
<?php
/*
 Template Name: Personal Assistants
 */
get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'pa', 'posts_per_page' => 6 ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

stuff here

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

This will only show whatever text I put where 'stuff here' is. As I am new to this I have no idea on how I should display the actual posts; I need some more php queries here to display the posts like it would a normal blog? I found the get_ queries, I have no idea how to construct it - all I can work out is  a bit of a hack where I use the permalink as a custom link menu item but I do also want to create a custom search, and categories sidebar too. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just put everything you want like a normal wordpress post or you can copy from the index.php loop

```
    get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'pa', 'posts_per_page' => 6 ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

stuff here
<?php 
$post->ID;
get_the_title();
get_permalink();
?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

This just a example of how you can use it

Comment: Thanks Fermin, this is great. I had a feeling it would look like this - then I can use get_excerpt etc everything I need to display. I will give it a try! :) I am now creating CPT manually instead of using a plug in so that I can understand it all better.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about the loop [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action) and [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), inside the loop the `post` object is available, you can get the `post` data there, this includes the content, the title etc. Example:

```
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<?php

//stuff here
the_title();
the_time();
the_content();

?>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you David - those links are great! I knew I had to call post things but was having trouble finding how.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you are looping through your posts, you need to use WordPress' Template Tags, which will display on your device such things as the post's title, featured image, excerpt, author, published date and more.  These Template Tags will be written in PHP. They are easy to understand and use. Here's an intro article: https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/template-tag/